# Get current username inside proxy.pac

Tags: networking, proxy

Is it possible to get the current username of the environment the `proxy.pac` file is running in? (*ie, on Windows desktop, the current logged in user*).

We have a new proxy that I want to direct certain users to for testing purposes before making it the default.

Comment: What proxy server is used?

Comment: That should be irrelevant since proxy.pac runs on the client, but we have both squid and sslsplit proxies running.